# typescript generic type inference in higher order function

Tags: typescript, generics

```
function generate<P extends object>(init: (p: P) => void) {
  return function (p: P): P {
    init(p)
    return p
  }
}

const g = generate(function AAA<T>(p: T) {
  console.log(p)
})

const result = g({
  x: 1
})

result.x // TS2339: Property 'x' does not exist on type '{}'.
```

The `generate` function is a higher order function and it seems typescript can't deduce the generic type `P`.

How can I make `generate` able to accept a generic typed function as parameter?

Comment: I found the new feature in Typescript 3.4 rc which is called "Propagated generic type arguments" in this blog: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-4-rc/ . This is exactly what I want!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript 3.4 makes huge improvements around the handling of generic type parameter forwarding. You can read the details [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30215).

While your code will not work as is in 3.4 either, we can get it to work if we change the `init` function to take in a generic tuple argument. This will cause type parameter forwarding to kick in:

```
function generate<A extends [any]>(init: (...p: A) => void) {
    return function (...p: A): A[0] {
        init(...p)
        return p
    }
}

const g = generate(function AAA<T>(p: T) {
    console.log(p)
})

const result = g({
    x: 1
})

result.x // ok now
```

You can test this code yourself if you run `npm install typescript@next`.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by type parameter forwarding?

Comment: @Wex The `<T>` on the parameter function is forwarded to the return of the `generate` function. The type parameter on `g` was not explicitly defined anywhere but instead comes from the fact that `init` was generic.